# MySQL error codes in .NET

Tags: mysql, .net, c++-cli

How to check what exception has occurred when an exception is thrown?

```
       try {
            MySqlConnection^ conDatabase = gcnew MySqlConnection(constring);
            MySqlCommand^ cmdDataBase = gcnew MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM database.data WHERE value =" + value + ";", conDatabase);
            MySqlDataReader^ myReader;
            conDatabase->Open();
            myReader = cmdDataBase->ExecuteReader();

            while (myReader->Read()) {
                count++;
            }
            conDatabase->Close();
        }
        catch (Exception^ ex) {
            error = ex->HResult;
            MessageBox::Show(ex->Message, ex->HResult.ToString());
        }
```

Specifically I want to check if there is no internet connection. Is `HResult` constant and stable? There are somethings called `MySqlError` and `MySqlErrorCode`, do I have to deal with them? I don't care about SQL injections.

Comment: The trap you are catching for is general exceptions.  It does not contain information specific to Database connectivity, query failures, etc. What you want is to add another catch before `Exception^ ex` for `MySqlException`  (case of text may be slightly different)

Comment: `ex->Number`? Will it be constant, stable?